# Get correct value in column sub total

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

In Power BI I am working with a matrix that shows a daily percentage.
When I add a column subtotal this sub total is summing up all the percentages for the selected days.
What I would like is that the Column sub total is showing the average percentage over the selected days.
[Picture of the matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0k7B.png)

Thanks a lot for looking at my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you calculate the percentage itself and on what granularity it exists in your data model, but you might want to play around with the `ISFILTERED` formula. Not sure what the name of the dimension ranging between 1 and 6 is in your graph, but let's call it `day number`. You can then do something like:

```
IF(ISFILTERED(day number), SUM(daily percentage), AVERAGE(daily percentage))
```

This checks if the daily percentage is filtered by the day number in the visual (matrix) or not. If it is, then it just takes the sum of the percentage (which is the percentage itself for any given day), otherwise it'll calculate the average percentage.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you pointed me in the correct direction by mentioning the granularity. I got i working by creating a measure that does the calculation. Thanks a lot for your help.